# R.v. $X$, $E[X^2]<\infty$. How to prove that $\mathrm{Var}[X\land a] \le \mathrm{Var}[X]$ for any real number $a$?

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, variance, covariance

As the title says, It looks simple, however not very intuitive. I finished it with the step function converging to it. However, it seems too complicated and I wonder would there be some elementary proof.

Comment: At first, $\mathsf{Var}[X^+]\le \mathsf{Var}[X]$, then  $\mathsf{Var}[X\wedge a]\le \mathsf{Var}[X]$

Comment: @JGWang True if I have the first one. But how?  T_T

Comment: $X\wedge a=a-(a-X)^+$.

Comment: @JGWang Oh I am wondering how to obtain the first one!

Comment: Since $\mathsf{cov}(X^+,X^-)=\mathsf{E}[X^+X^-]- \mathsf{E}[X^+] \mathsf{E}[X^-]=-\mathsf{E}[X^+] \mathsf{E}[X^-]<0$, then $\mathsf{var}[X]\ge \mathsf{var}[X^+]+\mathsf{var}[X^-]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\geq \mu=\mathrm E(X)$ we have
$$
\mathrm {Var} (X\wedge a) \leq \mathrm E[(X\wedge a-\mu)^2]
\\ = \mathrm E[(X-\mu)^2\mathbf 1_{X<a}] +\mathrm E[(a-\mu)^2\mathbf 1_{X\geq a}]
\\ \leq \mathrm E[(X-\mu)^2\mathbf 1_{X<a}]+ \mathrm E[(X-\mu)^2\mathbf 1_{X\geq a}]
=\mathrm{Var}(X).
$$

If $a\leq \mu$ we have
$$
\mathrm {Var} (X\wedge a) \leq \mathrm E[(X\wedge a-a)^2]
\\ = \mathrm E[(a-X)^2\mathbf 1_{X<a}] +\mathrm E[(a-a)^2\mathbf 1_{X\geq a}]
\\ \leq \mathrm E[(\mu-X)^2\mathbf 1_{X<a}]  \leq \mathrm {Var}(X).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $X=X\wedge a+(X-a)^+$, then
\begin{align*}
 \mathsf{var}[X]&=\mathsf{var}[X\wedge a]+\mathsf{var}[(X-a)^+]+2\cdot\mathsf{cov}(X\wedge a,(X-a)^+)\\
 &\ge \mathsf{var}[X\wedge a]+2\cdot\mathsf{cov}(X\wedge a,(X-a)^+).
\end{align*}
Meanwhile
\begin{align*}
 &\mathsf{cov}(X\wedge a,(X-a)^+)=\mathsf{cov}(X\wedge a-a,(X-a)^+)\\
 &\qquad =-\mathsf{cov}((X-a)^-,(X-a)^+)\\
 &\qquad=-\mathsf{E}[(X-a)^-(X-a)^+]+\mathsf{E}[(X-a)^-]\mathsf{E}[(X-a)^+]\\
 &\qquad=\mathsf{E}[(X-a)^-]\mathsf{E}[(X-a)^+]\ge 0,
\end{align*}
therefore
$$ \mathsf{var}[X]\ge \mathsf{var}[X\wedge a]. 
$$